# How to add basic shapes in StageXL?

Tags: canvas, dart, stagexl

I'm trying to add a circle to a canvas using StageXL. I have tried the following but had no success:

```dart
Shape shape = new Shape()
    ..graphics.beginPath()
    ..graphics.circle(50, 50, 50)
    ..graphics.closePath()
    ..graphics.moveTo(20, 20)
    ..graphics.fillColor(0xFF8ED6FF)
    ..graphics.strokeColor(Color.Blue, 5)
    ..addTo(stage);
```

Any idea what I'm missing here? Thanks.

Comment: This works fine for me. Try adding some more of your code to the question, since the problem isn't in the code you posted.

Comment: I found the cause of the problem. I had to turn off webGL in the Stage constructor.`Stage stage = new Stage(querySelector('#stage'), webGL: false);` But, I don't know why enabling webGL causes this issue?

Comment: @PixelElephant Thank you for your comment. It made me look for the cause of the error in other parts of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is :

"The WebGL renderer is highly optimized to draw textures (BitmapDatas) but does not support vector graphics yet. If you want to draw Graphics display objects please use the applyCache method which renders the vector graphics to a texture or do not opt-in for the WebGL renderer."

I found that in the changelog here : https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stagexl